# How to use array_column or foreach to get result

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

This is my array,with the use of array_column or any loop I want to replace keys as value of next element .I don't want to change parent array index

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
                [total] => 100000
                [content] => abc
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [total] => 200000
                [content] => def
            )
        )
```

This is the array I would like to have.

```
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [11] => 100000
                [content] => abc
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [22] => 200000
                [content] => def
            )
        )
```

Comment: show us your implementation...

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: You have to try anything at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple Try this:-

```
$array = array(
    '0'=>array('id'=> 10,'total'=> 100000,'content' => 'abc'),
    '1'=>array('id'=> 11,'total'=> 200000,'content' => 'def')
);

foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $array[$key][$val['id']] = $val['total'];
    unset($array[$key]['total']);
    unset($array[$key]['id']);
 }
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); die;    // print array data here
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using 'foreach' to modify existing array works perfect, but 'array_walk' is just more expressive, because it was designed for this task.

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'id' => 11,
        'total' => 10000,
        'content' => 'abc'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 22,
        'total' => 200000,
        'content' => 'def'
    ]
];

array_walk($array, function(&$row) {
    $row[$row['id']] = $row['total'];
    unset($row['id'], $row['total']);
});

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with array_map function

```
$new = array_map(function($x) {
                 return [ $x['id']=> $x['total'], 'content' => $x['content']]; },
                 $array);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/909187)